# Function click jquery apply for multiple element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here's what I've got:  [jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/suxedung/5wLJf/1/)

html:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap_demo">
 <input type="button" class="click" value="click" onClick="function" />
</div>
<div class="wrap_demo">
 <input type="button" class="click" value="click" onClick="function" />
</div>
<div class="wrap_demo">
 <input type="button" class="click" value="click" onClick="function" />
</div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $( ".click" ).click(function() {
       if($(".wrap_demo").height()==50)
        $(".wrap_demo").animate({height: '300px'});
        else  $(".wrap_demo").animate({height: '50px'});
    });
});
```

css:

```
 .wrap_demo{
width:300px;
height:50px;
border:1px solid black;
float:left;
margin-top:20px;
position:relative;
}

.click{
display:block;
width:40px;
height:40px;
background:white;
border-radius:50%;
border:1px solid black;
position:absolute;
top:5px;
left:170px;
font-size:12px;
line-height:30px;
text-align:center;
cursor:pointer;
}
.click:focus{
outline:none;
}
```

I want when click button "click" then jquery function only open wrap_demo is parent of button click I've click. How do function jquery only animate 1 parent wrap_demo ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `$(this)` to target current button which was clicked as well as `.parent()` or `.closest()` to get only the parent `.wrap_demo` of clicked button:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $( ".click" ).click(function() {
       var wrap_demo = $(this).closest(".wrap_demo"); // or $(this).parent();
       if(wrap_demo.height()==50)
        wrap_demo.animate({height: '300px'});
        else wrap_demo.animate({height: '50px'});
    });
});
```

Please note that you don't need to use inline `onClick` event handler here since you've already applied `.click()`, so just remove it.

Another side note is that you can include jQuery directly from `jsFiddle` instead of using `<script>` tag by choosing jQUery version from `Frameworks & Extensions` tab

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5wLJf/3/)**

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
$(function(){
 $( ".click" ).click(function() {
           if($(this).parent(".wrap_demo").height()==50)
            $(this).parent(".wrap_demo").animate({height: '300px'});
            else  $(this).parent(".wrap_demo").animate({height: '50px'});
        });
});
```

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/Ea6Ns/)**

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
.wrap_demo{
    width:300px;
    height:50px;
    border:1px solid black;
    float:left;
    margin-top:20px;
    position:relative;
}
.click{
    display:block;
    width:40px;
    height:40px;
    background:white;
    border-radius:50%;
    border:1px solid black;
    position:absolute;
    top:5px;
    left:170px;
    font-size:12px;
    line-height:30px;
    text-align:center;
    cursor:pointer;
}
.click:focus{outline:none;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap_demo">
<input type="button" class="click" value="click" />
</div>
<div class="wrap_demo">
    <input type="button" class="click" value="click" />
</div>
<div class="wrap_demo">
    <input type="button" class="click" value="click" />
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".click").click(function() {
            $('.wrap_demo').height(50).removeClass('toggled');
            var parent = $(this).closest('.wrap_demo');
            if($(parent).hasClass('toggled'))
            {
                $(parent).stop().animate({"height": "50px"});
                $(parent).removeClass('toggled');
            }
            else
            {
                $(parent).stop().animate({"height": "300px"});
                $(parent).addClass('toggled');
            }
        });
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```